# daemon startup script reporting incorrect status

Tags: bash

I am wanting to use a startup script that calls up iperf at boot time as well as something that I can specify with the chkconfig utility and just control iperf from the command line as a typical service if I so choose. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# chkconfig: - 50 50
# description: iperf

DAEMON=/usr/bin/iperf
service=iperf
info=$(pidof /usr/bin/iperf)

case "$1" in
      start)
              $DAEMON -s -D
              ;;
      stop)
              pidof $DAEMON | xargs kill -9
              ;;
      status)
              if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
              then
              echo $DAEMON pid $info is running!!!
              else
              echo $DAEMON is NOT running!!!
              fi
              ;;
      restart)
              $DAEMON stop
              $DAEMON start
              ;;
      *)
              echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
              exit 1
              ;;
esac
```

Everything works fine so far. I can start and stop the service using the script. I can add it to chkconfig no problems. But I have noticed that even if iperf is not running, when I use the status command it still returns it as running:

With it running:

```
 # service iperf status
/usr/bin/iperf pid 34828 is running!!!
```

Without it running:

```
# service iperf status
/usr/bin/iperf pid is running!!!
```

To this point I have not been able to figure out why this is happening. Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, poorly. `pidof iperf || echo not running`

Comment: Also don't use `kill -9` unless the program is buggy, in which case don't run it at all.

Comment: You should also look into the lsb/init functions provided by the various distributions. They have functions for much of this designed to make your life easier.

Comment: the pidof iperf || echo not running method is not working. Can you post an answer with what the actual code would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking by saying:

```
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
```

And you run the script with:

```
service iperf status
```

So my guess is that `ps -ef | ... | grep iperf` also finds the call of this script. You can check by printing the output of `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service`.

Comment: What do you mean "it finds the call of the script"? How would you do this differently to get the results expected?

Comment: When you call it you say `service iperf status`, so there you have a process with `iperf` in its name that `ps -ef | grep iperf` will count. Then, you have the `grep` itself that you grep out. All together, if it is running you have 2 processes and if it is not, you have 1. As I said, print `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep iperf` to confirm.

Comment: From command line when its running it finds one - the actual iperf process. When its not running that command finds nothing.

Comment: I think you were right. I had to run watch -n0 "ps aux | grep iperf" in order to catch the "service iperf status" coming through. I changed my script to use netstat to find the process and now it works correctly.